# XAML - Change icon dependent on binding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I'm creating a listview and binding data, which is working ok, but I can't work out how to change an icon based on a data value.

```
<Border Background="Aquamarine" Grid.Column="0">
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
</Border>
<Border Background="Yellow" Grid.Column="1">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding FName}" Margin="5" />
</Border>
```

So the SymbolIcon is currently a folder but how do I change it to another icon if the underlying data set has a boolean value denoting that folder is false?

In fact is there a way of changing any other styling in the following textblock, based on the actual data underlying that field?

Comment: Bind the `Symbol` property to change the icon.  The `Symbol` property is one of the named constants from the [Symbol Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.c.ontrols.symbol).  See that link for the different available values

Comment: thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `Symbol` based on a `bool` property by binding it using an `IValueConverter`.  Have the `IValueConverter` convert `true` to "Folder" and `false` to "SomethingElse" (whatever icon you want for false).

The binding would look something like:

```
<SymbolIcon Symbol="{Binding Path=TheBooleanProperty, Converter=NameOfTheIValueConverterResource" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
```